# Unable to upload image to a Coldfusion REST API Service

Tags: rest, coldfusion

I am using CF10 REST API Service and trying to upload an a profile picture for a user.

The service method tries to save this image to a destination:

```
<cfcomponent rest="true"
             restpath="/users">
    <cffunction name="saveProfilePicture"
                access="remote"
                httpmethod="POST"
                restpath="{userid}/profilePicture"
                returntype="any">

        <cfargument name="uploadedImage" required="true"/>
        <cfargument name="userid" required="true" restargsource="Path"/>

        <cffile
        action="upload"
        destination="#upload_path#"
        fileField="uploadedImage"
        result="profilePicture"
        accept="image/jpg"
        />
    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

I am trying to call this service as follows:

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="#path#/users/#userid#/profilePicture">
<input type="file" name="uploadedImage"/>
<input type="submit" name="btn_submit_profilePicture" id="btn_submit_profilePicture" 
value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

After I make this call I get an error message "Unsupported Media Type".

I get the same issue if I use cfhttp:

```
<cfhttp url="#path#/users/#userid#/profilePicture" 
result="restResult" method="POST" multipart="true">
<cfhttpparam file="someimage.jpg" mimetype="image/jpg" 
name="uploadedImage" type="file"/>
</cfhttp>
```

I have tried to search around but couldn't find a solution that works. 
I can't use a framework as of now as most of the API is already implemented over CF REST API so guess I am stuck with it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What is the actual mime type of the file you are attempting to upload? Changes were made to the `cffile` tag in ColdFusion 10 that it actually evaluates the file's mime type and not just the file extension by default. See this blog entry - [http://www.sagarganatra.com/2012/03/coldfusion-10-cffile-restricting-file.html](http://www.sagarganatra.com/2012/03/coldfusion-10-cffile-restricting-file.html). At the end he includes an example of using the `fileGetMimeType` function to get a file's mime type. Create a test page and use that against the file you are uploading to see what mime type it sees.

Comment: I see you have `accept="image/jpg"` in the cffile tag of your cfc. Did you upload a true jpg file?

Comment: @Miguel-F @jules ok so I checked the mime type of the file using fileGetMimeType and it was `image/jpeg`. I made changes in the cfhttp call and also in the service cfc to work with this mime type but I still get the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like the following and test it.

```
<cfcomponent rest="true"
         restpath="/users">
<cffunction name="saveProfilePicture"
            access="remote"
            httpmethod="POST"
            restpath="{userid}/profilePicture"
            returntype="any">

    <cfargument name="uploadedImage" restargsource="form"/>
    <cfargument name="userid" restargsource="Path"/>

    <cffile
    action="upload"
    destination="#upload_path#"
    result="arguments.uploadedImage"
    accept="image/jpg,image/jpeg"
    />
</cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```